# Does Swift's Double.random(in: -1...1) return -1 and 1?

Tags: swift

I actually tried to check for myself, but found it impossible because the probability was too small.
I just wanted a clear answer.

```swift
var minValue = 0.0
var maxValue = 0.0
for i in 1...Int.max {
    let randomValue = Double.random(in: -1...1)
    minValue = min(minValue, randomValue)
    maxValue = max(maxValue, randomValue)

    if i.isMultiple(of: 1_000_000) {
        print("min, max:", minValue, maxValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: It does, but it's astonishingly unlikely. You essentially trying to guess a [52 bit fraction and a 1 bit sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). That's like getting an exact guess on a hypothetical UInt53. *plus* that's ignoring all the sub-normal values

Comment: Why are you constraining this question to two values? Extrapolate from `Double.random(in: x...x)` always returning `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that the answer is "yes" by reading the documentation of [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/random(in:)-5o5ha), [`ClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange), and also [`ClosedRange.contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/contains(_:)).

`random(in: range)` is said to return:

> A random value within the bounds of `range`.

Well, are `-1` and `1` "within the bounds of" `-1...1`? The docs of `ClosedRange` says "yes":

> You create a `ClosedRange` instance by using the closed range operator
> (`...`).
>
> ```
> let throughFive = 0...5
> ```
>
> A `ClosedRange` instance contains both its lower bound and its upper
> bound.
>
> ```
> throughFive.contains(3)
> // true
> throughFive.contains(10)
> // false
> throughFive.contains(5)
> // true
> ```

See also the discussion in `ClosedRange.contains`:

> A `ClosedRange` instance contains both its lower and upper bound. element is contained in the range if it is between the two bounds or equal to either bound.

So theoretically, `Double.random(in: -1...1)` does have a (very small) chance of returning the bounds of the range, -1 or 1, as they are "within the range".

You can show that the bounds of the range can indeed be returned by `random` by creating a range such as `1...1` - there is only one element to return!

```
Double.random(in: 1...1) // will always return 1, which is the bound
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but here is a more efficient way to check if the bound (upper in this case) is ever reached

```
var randomValue = -1.0
for i in 1...Int.max {
    randomValue = Double.random(in: randomValue...1)
    print(randomValue)
    if randomValue == 1 {
        print("limit reached")
        break
    }
}
```